# Show a confirmation/dialogbox in asp.net(c#)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, dialog, popup

Functionality I need to achieve is: 
Confirmbutton_Click

Show a popup/dialogbox:

On click of Yes, I need to validate Email-Id and other personal details submitted.
    If validation fails, show error messages and return false.
    If email-id and other details are correct, then hide/show few Divs.

I had achieved this functionality in jQuery but now I am supposed to do it in server side. Firstly because the Divs were not showing up each time correctly and secondly due to security concern.

The suggestions I got on googling ask to write complete code (in script tag) at server side. That would be too much as I need to validate many fields.
Also, is there a way I can just do the validations at client side and come back to server side and show my Divs depending upon the validation result ? The client script will be executed before server side, so it is achievable.

I don't want to create a new popup page for this.

If anyone could help me with correct code or pointers to one, how to validate and show divs(showing div to be done from server side).

### UPDATED:

I am midway, if anyone could help me any:

In page load(not post back) I hv added:

```
btnConfirm.Attributes.Add("onclick", "if(confirm('Confirm - Are you sure you want to go ahead.')) onConfirm(); else return false;");
```

In jQuery code i have added validations as:

```
function onConfirm() {    
    //Check if email-id is not blank, else show message and return to the page
    if (isBlank($('#emailAddress').val()) == false) {
        $('#errorBlankEmail').show();
        return false;
    }
}
    //Text validation functions
    function isBlank(valueSent) {
        if ($.trim(valueSent) == "")
            return false;
        else
            return true;
}
```

and the button code as:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnConfirm" runat="server"   Text="Confirm"  onclick="Confirm_Click" />
```

And the server side code for this:

```
protected void Confirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        divConfirm.Visible = true;
    }
```

Now when I click on button, it works until I validate and validation fails, it executes the server side code. Is there a way where I can avoid the server-side code if result is false in client click code ?

Comment: can you share some code?

Comment: Are you using server side validations or client side validations?

Comment: I have not coded yet for server side validation which I want here. And I want client side validations as i already have a function for it. I am happy to call it from server side.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try using http://www.telerik.com/ ASP.net AJAX controls, or Ajax Control Toolkit Modal Extender.  Ive used both and they are exactly what your after.

Comment: Craig, thanks for the suggestion. I am familiar with the telerik controls but in this project, the max i can use is javascript/jQuery.

Comment: No problem ;) sorry I couldnt of been more help

Answer (score 0):

I woudn't suggest to do it this way , but maybe this will point you to better solution.

From server side as you mentioned you can use static function

```
var script = @"<script> $("#somediv").dialog()  </script>", false);
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "some", , false);
```

(#somediv) is encaplulated with user control and contains all validation logic. 
The problem is server validation of your div , since after postback on div ( on server side validation) your div will be closed , and again you need to pup it up from server , 
This approach will mess up things ... I'd use new popup window that will return result.

Answer (score 0):

you won't get a confirmation on the server. the server has not concept of user interaction within the request/response. it can only receive the request, process it, and send a response.

what you can do is send a request to generate a response which will ask for the user to confirm. the user would then click "yes" which will create another request. the server will receive the request, process the request and send a response.

but what you cannot do is ask the user to confirm the request while processing it on the server. that confirmation must have already been done.

you can validate the request the request on the server, but that is just standard validation. nothing fancy to do there.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [jQuery ui Dialog - Modal Confirmation](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation)

and on confirm use __doPostback to fire the event 'Confirmbutton_Click'

It is just another way, but it won't be as easy as telerik controls..

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height:140,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Confirm": function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    __doPostBack('#<%= Confirmbutton.UniqueID %>', null)
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

And as html,

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Empty the recycle bin?">
    <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 20px 0;"></span>These items will be permanently deleted and cannot be recovered. Are you sure?</p>
</div>
<asp:button id="Confirmbutton" runat="Server" OnClick="Confirmbutton_Click" style="display:none;" />
```

Comment: Sen, I am using jQuery slider controls which use modified widget classes. Also I am using 2 buttons calling different popup which in return have different functionalities. Hence when they refer widget classes, it messes up stuff. But still I will try again. Thanks for suggestion.